# alternatives to clonezilla

Tags: backup

My clonezilla no longer will offer an external drive as /home/image_part. It use to work. I don't know what happened and I have tried three different drives.  I regularly backup my development directory with backintime but i am getting nervous about it.

Other than Clonezilla is there an alternative? It does not need to be free, it just needs to be easy and idiot proof. I could back up to S3 if needed or a some server, or one of my three external HD's. My external drives are 256M, 1G and 2G. I did see this discussed up here but no mention of "idiot-proof" or a commercial service.

Suggestions?

Comment: have you tried a newer or older version of clonezilla, or recreate a new boot usb drive for clonezilla?

Comment: I have a commercially made usb with bootable clonezilla on it that I bought

Comment: which apparently is not working for you, and why I suggested alternatives to experiment with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to create system image to clone drive or partition, gnome-disk-utility could do the job. ubuntu come with gnome-disk-utility in thier live CD, so you'll just need to boot into live CD, select "try ubuntu" and you can create disk or partition image using gnome-disk-utility.

Edit: How to use Gnome-Disk-Utility from Live CD\USB

1. Boot into usb and make sure to click on `try ubuntu`..
2. After ubuntu has boot up, click `show application` button located on bottom left of the bar.
3. Type in "disk" in the search bar, program call `Disks` should show up and click on it..
4. Click on the triple dot located on the left of the minimize button, you should able to see the option `Create Disk Image...` to create the image of the whole drive.
5. If you want to create image of a partition, click on a partition and click on the gear icon, you should able to see the option `Create Partition Image...`
6. Once you click on either `Create Disk Image...` or `Create Partition Image...`, just follow the instruction.

if you dont dare to try on the server, create a virtual machine and play with the tools until you are comfortable with it.

Comment: It may be a little primitive, but this is the method I use. Just about anything from dd to mkusb, Rufus, Etcher, SDC, etc, can restore the image.

Comment: >>boot into live CD   - what does this mean?

Comment: it's ubuntu bootable disk, unlike window, you can use ubuntu or many linux distro with just a bootable disk, no installation require and that is called a live CD.

Comment: Some people say "Live USB".

Comment: OK. My Live USB finally arrived!  Do you know where there are any written directions on performing such a procedure?I  am really nervous about effing up the machine I have working.

Comment: sorry for late reply, updated my answer with more information...

Comment: I think at this point it could very well be named "live USB" by default, and maybe one could mention that this is the same thing that used to be historically called "live CD"s.

Comment: Also, OP probably could use a mention of how to obtain an Ubuntu ISO and how to prepare a bootable USB themselves (as opposed to the procedure of buying a commercially prepared and distributed one, which they have the only experience in). :)